# Make geom_histogram display x-axis labels as integers instead of numerics

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, axis-labels, xticks

I have a `data.frame` that has counts for several groups:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(group = sample(c("a","b"),200,replace = T),
                 n = round(runif(200,1,2)))
df$n <- as.integer(df$n)
```

And I'm trying to display a histogram of `df$n`, facetted by the `group` using `ggplot2`'s `geom_histogram`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = n)) + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(~group) + theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Any idea how to get `ggplot2` to label the x-axis ticks with the integers the histogram is summarizing rather than the numeric values it is currently showing?

Comment: `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(df$n))`

Answer (score 1):

You could tweak this by the `binwidth` argument of `geom_histogram`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = n)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5) + 
  facet_grid(~group) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Another example:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(group = sample(c("a","b"),200,replace = T),
                 n = round(runif(200,1,5)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = n)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5) + 
  facet_grid(~group) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can manually specify the breaks with `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 2))`. Alternatively, you can set the breaks and labels separately as well.